# GCC Argument Type Error?

Tags: c, gcc, arguments

I'm pretty new at this, so I'm sure this is an amateur mistake. I'm trying to make a basic financial calculator and keep running into this error when I try to compile:

findn.c: In function ‘main’:
findn.c:36:3: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat]
findn.c:50:3: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat]

As far as I can tell, the argument *is* a float type. What gives? Also feel free to point out anything else, I'm sure my code is sloppy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void findN (float PV, float FV, float interest)
{
float iDec = interest / 100;
float onePlusI = iDec + 1;
float leftSide = FV / PV;
float logOne = log(leftSide);
float logTwo = log(onePlusI);
float N = logOne / logTwo;
printf("%f\n", N);
}

void findI (float PV, float FV, float N)
{
float leftSide = FV / PV;
float expN = 1 / N;
float iPlusOne = pow(leftSide, expN);
float iDec = iPlusOne - 1;
float interest = iPlusOne * 100;
printf("%f\n", interest);
}

main ( )
{
int userInput;
printf("Press 1 to find Present Value, 2 to find Future Value, 3 to find Interest, or 4 to find Number of Periods\n");
scanf("%d", &userInput);
if (userInput = 3)
    {
    float Pres3;
    float Fut3;
    float Num3;
    printf("Enter Present Value\n");
    scanf("%f", Pres3);
    printf("Enter Future Value\n");
    scanf("%f", &Fut3);
    printf("Enter the Number of Periods\n");
    scanf("%f", &Num3);
    findN(Pres3, Fut3, Num3);
    }

else if (userInput = 4)
    {
    float Pres4;
    float Fut4;
    float Int4;
    printf("Enter Present Value\n");
    scanf("%f", Pres4);
    printf("Enter Future Value\n");
    scanf("%f", &Fut4);
    printf("Enter interest\n");
    scanf("%f", &Int4);
    findN(Pres4, Fut4, Int4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (userInput = 3)
```

this is wrong, here you are not comparing again value `3`, you are assigning value `3` to `userInput`. Use equality operator `==` instead of `=` assignment operator.

Then:

```
scanf("%f", Pres3);
```

you have to pass a pointer to `Pres3`. Use:

```
scanf("%f", &Pres3);
```

instead.

These two issues are repeated elsewhere in your program.

Finally, `main()` is not a valid way to declare `main` in C. Use `int main(void)`.

Comment: `Pres4` has the same issue btw

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `scanf("%f", Pres3);` instead of `scanf("%f", &Pres3);`. It's complaining about the fact that the argument isn't a *pointer*.

The confusion between `float` and `double` is probably because you're on a machine where `float` is the same as `double`.

Comment: No, the confusion between `float` and `double` is because a `float` argument is promoted to `double` when passed to a variadic function such as `scanf`. `float` and `double` are *never* the same type (even if they happen to be the same size, which is rare).

Comment: What I don't get is, why is the compiler complaining about "argument 2 has type ‘double’" instead of uint16_t (or whatever the pointer size is).